# Syntax for simple polygon overlap in Oracle Spatial

Tags: oracle-spatial

I have a situation where I need to check if any polygons from a table occupy any of the same space as a given polygon in oracle spatial. Currently I am running SQL like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SDO_RELATE(MY_TABLE.GEOM, ?, 'mask=OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT+EQUAL+INSIDE+COVEREDBY+CONTAINS+COVERS') = 'TRUE'
```

This is quite slow in many cases, and in the Oracle documentation, they recommend splitting it out for performance ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_operat.htm#i78531 ), making it even longer (Personally I would live with the performance hit because the syntax is insane) :

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SDO_RELATE(MY_TABLE.GEOM, ?, 'mask=OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT') = 'TRUE'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SDO_RELATE(MY_TABLE.GEOM, ?, 'mask=EQUAL') = 'TRUE'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SDO_RELATE(MY_TABLE.GEOM, ?, 'mask=INSIDE+COVEREDBY') = 'TRUE'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SDO_RELATE(MY_TABLE.GEOM, ?, 'mask=CONTAINS+COVERS') = 'TRUE';
```

Is there a better way of doing this? It seems to be quite a long syntax for what in theory should be quite a common operation! (And I suspect that there would also be a performance boost to using such a function if it exists.) I tried using the SDO_OVERLAPS function but it does not catch cases where the polygons are equal or one is fully inside the other.

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to use `DISJOINT` to make it simpler, maybe `... 'mask=DISJOINT') = 'FALSE' `?

Comment: @david - Good idea - I have been able to make it work with 'mask=DISJOINT+TOUCH') <> 'TRUE'. I will need to test to see if this is indeed faster - if all else fails, at least the syntax is shorter